# Листающийся журнал на флэше

Tags: flash

Ребят, подскажите или ссылку дайте с описанием как сделать журнал как здесь onpages._ru, только что он сам листался, без событий мыши. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужна качественная листалка - флэша не избежать.

http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/flex-book-component-beta - вот одна из лучших.

Там есть автоматическое листание страниц (прочитайте в доках).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь - [MegaZine3](http://www.megazine3.de/home.html):

> MegaZine3 is a Flash driven pageflip engine that recreates the look and feel of actual books or magazines on the screen. And much more...

Можно использовать как есть или взглянуть на исходники и переиспользовать.

Но вообще для этого эффекта Flash не обязателен, сейчас он достигается с помощью CSS3 или jQuery: [Sencha Animator Demo: Page Flipping in Pure CSS](http://dev.sencha.com/animator/demos/pageflip/).